# CouchDB "authenticated user" role

Tags: couchdb

I am working on setting up authentication for an app with a CouchDB backend, and was wondering if there was a role analogous to "_admin" for authenticated users.

I have a database with config information that all users that access the app need to be able to read from. (I plan to prevent writes with a validate_doc_update rule).

Is there a system-defined role that I can use, or will I have to assign an appropriate role to each user? (I'd like to avoid this, as it just adds overhead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no special, system-defined role for authenticated users. You can check if the user's name is set in the userCtx, though. It's only set if the user is successfully authenticated. You get it as the third parameter in the [validate_doc_update function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions).